# CSS: Flex equal height columns and vertical center content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling to get the content in left and right columns to be vertically middle aligned

**https://jsfiddle.net/kLm7j7zq/**

```
<div class="equalizer">
  <div class="block1">
    <div class="inner"><p>
    Block 1
    </p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.</div>
  <div class="block2"><div class="inner2"><p>
    Block 2
    </p></div></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
    .equalizer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  *{
    display: flex;
    background: pink;
    flex:1;
    align-content: center;
   }
  .block2{background: yellow;}
}
```

How do I fix it and importantly have it work on Safari and Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c6v0cp2c/1/)

```css
.equalizer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: center;
    background: pink;
  }
  .equalizer * {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .equalizer .block2 {
    background: yellow;
  }
  

  .block1,  .inner2 {
      align-self: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="equalizer">
  <div class="block1">
   <div class="inner">
    <p>
     Block 1
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim
   maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
   adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis
   id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia.
   Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt
   commodi.
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
   <div class="inner2">
    <p>
     Block 2
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any way I can have Block 2 (with Yellow bg) be the same height?

Comment: `.block1,  .inner2 {
      align-self: center;
  }`

Comment: Great! Thanks again!